# Edit text in microsoft word file c#

Tags: c#, text, steganography

The task is pretty simple steganography: First of all, I'm reading some text (secret message) from txt file, then I need to open a Microsoft Word doc with some random text in it and search matching symbols from my message and inside Word file, then increase the font of found symbols inside Word file and close it. Explanation might be a bit rough, so here is an example: message: "secret", text from word file: "soviet economy has been reorganized to..", after the script word file must be something like "SoviEt eConomy has been REorganized To..". What is the best way I can do that without diving deep into libraries?
Current code:

```
class Program
    {
      
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = @"C:\Users\evluc\Desktop\text.txt";
            string message = String.Concat(File.ReadAllLines(path));
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void Encrypt(string message)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < message.Length; i++)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

I'm planning to do the encryption inside "Encrypt" method

Comment: Downvoted because this is hardly a question, more like a request for code. You need to talk to Word. Numerous examples in SO for that,

Comment: Your question is too broad..